# How to add new row to an already existing DataTable on Runtime in C# MVC on Runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datatable

I have a datatable 'tblTest'. When I try to add next row, the first row will get deleted. I need to add data as the second row. Find my code below.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable("tblTest"); // Declare as Global.
public JsonResult SaveTestData(string itemCode,int quantity)
{
    dt.Columns.Add("ItemCode", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Quantity", typeof(int));       
    DataRow dr;
    dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["ItemCode"] = itemCode;
    dr["Quantity"] = quantity;
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    return Json(1);
}
```

The 'SaveTestData' function repeats and need to add rows as the next row.

Comment: Because each request initializes a new instance of your Controller (so `dt` is a new (empty) `DataTable`). The web is stateless. You need to persist your data somewhere (e.g. to a database)

Comment: If DataTable already has `ItemCode` and `Quantity` columns then what's the point of adding these columns again and again?

Comment: @mmushtaq, The issue is that it doesn't - its a new instance of `DataTable` each time.

Comment: @Stephen Muecke , Is there any method to store data in the MVC Controller?,ie, I have multiple rows so  I need to store the entire data to the database as a one time process.

Comment: Then store it in a temporary table in a database. Or you could use `Session` (so long as you understand the implications)

Comment: How can I add multiple rows to a session as a table?

Comment: Just store the `DataTable` in `Session`, and get it again in the method, add the row and save it back to `Session`

Comment: But why are you just posting all the data from the view in one action (this is a very odd design)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store DataTable in Session, like this:

```
public JsonResult SaveTestData(string itemCode, int quantity)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable("tblTest"); // Declare as Global.
    // A table saved in session
    if (Session["tblTest"] != null)
    {
        dt = (DataTable)Session["tblTest"];
    }
    else // create new table and store in session
    {
        dt.Columns.Add("ItemCode", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Quantity", typeof(int));
    }


    DataRow dr;
    dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["ItemCode"] = itemCode;
    dr["Quantity"] = quantity;
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);

    //store new row in session
    Session["tblTest"] = dt;

    return Json(1);
}
```

Comment: It's my pleasure :)